# How did the Soviet Union support the development of their atomic bomb in 1949?

Tags: united-states, soviet-union, nuclear-weapons

The [Manhattan Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project) cost the United States a reported $2 billion. The Soviet Union managed to come up with an A-bomb four years later, even though their economy was about one third the size of America's, and half the size of German-controlled Europe's in the early 1940s. Given this fact, where did they come up with the money for the bomb?

Comment: Isn't that what a centralized economy is good for?

Comment: @DKNguyen: You have the makings of a good answer. Could you provide one?

Comment: I don't know enough. I just was never really surprised that a vast resource-wealthy, and populous country under a dictatorship would be able to focus the resources necessary to protect its own existence by doing something that had already been proven could be done.

Comment: You cannot meaningfully compare the budgets: Converting dollar to ruble according to the nominal exchange rate is pointless; internal prices were different, salaries, much of the Soviet labor was "free" (GULAG)...

Comment: @MoisheKohan: One thing that bothers me is that of the best known 40-45 nuclear scientists, about one-third were western, one third were German, and one third were Jews from German-occupied Europe who, of course fled to the west. Maybe the Soviets had a lot of good scientists that we didn't know about.

Comment: They had first rate theoretical physicists and mathematicians working on the project. The most famous is Kurchatov, the head of the project. You probably also heard of Sakharov.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, there was no shade on the Soviet nuclear scientists; though other branches of Soviet science were not always as fortunate.

Comment: I suggest, including at least [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_atomic_bomb_project) Wikipedia article in your question, indicating initial research. It will also give you names of some Soviet physicists working on the project and the importance of stolen information.

Comment: Or even reference to the [Russian-language Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%8B), which is much more detailed.

Comment: @Tom Au might be worth pointing out that some of these German scientists also played a role in the Soviet bomb project after the war.

Comment: Suggestion: emphasize "money" and detail that this means allocation of resources, economic, personnel, raw material, intellect, theory and practice? How was this prioritized, how did they 'keep the books in balance' (or not…)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Op's comparison of value is a red herring. Cost of living was dramatically lower in the Soviet Union than in the U.S., even at the time, so raw exchange rate creates a completely meaningless value comparison. Only for international purchases outside the Soviet Block would it have any meaning.

It's important to realize that the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs, though both "atomic" (a terrible descriptive, as all of chemistry is *atomic* energy and we're really talking *nuclear* energy in regards to *fission* and *fusion* bombs), were very different beasts. One was a dead-simple uranium bomb requiring no testing at all; while the second was vastly more complex, and when finally tested as *Trinity* not all the designers were confident of success.

So what is the key significance of the differences? Fuel supply. The Little Boy uranium bomb required enriched uranium as fuel, which prior to key engineering developments in late September 1945, could only be produced, even with the vast resources of Manhattan, at a rate of about 1 bomb every 6 months. The scientific and engineering requirements for Little Boy were solved quite early at Los Alamos; and then the team simply waited for sufficient fuel to be available.

However every uranium-fueled *atomic pile* rapidly produces sufficient plutonium fuel for a Fat Man bomb every 7 to 10 days. However the Fat Man bomb design was soon realized to be far more complex than for Little Boy. This is where the bulk of the Los Alamos effort was spent from 1943 to August 1945.

*Brief aside: The question is often asked: Why drop the Nagasaki bomb? Wasn't Hiroshima sufficient? The presumed answer is no, due to the Japanese refusal to answer or acknowledge the surrender demand following Hiroshima. There was no secret about the difficulties and time requirements for enriching uranium - it's the first concern encountered by every scientist, in every national bomb project, and why Iran still hasn't got a bomb. (Their centrifuges used for enrichment keep blowing up for mysterious reasons.) Nagasaki sent a very clear message to every physicist and informed politician around the Globe: "**We SOLVED the uranium enrichment problem. Take that!**"
And **that** is why Hirohito forced the War Cabinet to surrender.*

Now look at the initial  [test history](http://www-ns.iaea.org/downloads/rw/waste-safety/north-test-site-final.pdf) of the Soviet Union:

1. [**RD-1** - 29 August 1949](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1949%E2%80%9351_Soviet_nuclear_tests): claimed 22 ktons (same as Nagasaki) but believed to be under 20 ktons (more like Hiroshima).
2. **RD-2** - 24 September 1951: 38 ktons - even greater than Nagasaki.

This initial speculation on my part was incorrect. Classified documents released in the 1990's confirm that The RD-1 nuclear test in 1949 was an implosion-type plutonium bomb very similar to Fat Man. However the Soviet development continued for many years after WW@ to be constrained by access to uranium, as noted in the update below. Their uranium access was so constrained that even plutonium bomb development and test were limited by it.

<s>The obvious conclusion is that the Soviets completed a simpler  Hiroshima-type bomb (despite Beria's insistence and claim that it match Nagasaki) in 1949; and a  much more complex Nagasaki type plutonium bomb only 25 months later. A definitive determination would likely be possible by inspection of fallout from the two bombs, but I haven't found yet that analysis online.</s>

Remember the main obstacle to a Hiroshima-type bomb is just the time required to enrich sufficient uranium. it's not a complex device. Los Alamos didn't even bother with a test, their confidence was so great.

Finally, I have doubts that any intelligence received from Fuchs (or others) had a significant effect on the Soviet timeline. It's like being given the answers to a test - but betting your life on your understanding. What a coup it might have been for the entire Soviet team to blow itself up in an "accident" due to planted incorrect intelligence! All such received intelligence really does is give you an answer crib to check your own calculations against. That's useful, but not critical.

---

Update:

Here is [a very good summary of the early Soviet bomb development](http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/Soviet_atomic_bomb_project?View=embedded%27%27).  My supposition above about RD-1 is apparently incorrect; it was a plutonium bomb of  design comparable to Nagasaki. Rather, speed of Soviet bomb development seems to have been constrained by [uranium supply](https://www.spokesmanbooks.com/Spokesman/PDF/medvedev69.pdf).

Some excerpts, [with my comments in trailing brackets]:

> Alexei Kojevnikov has estimated, based on newly released Soviet documents, that the primary way in which the espionage may have sped up the Soviet project was that it allowed Khariton to avoid dangerous tests to determine the size of the critical mass: "tickling the dragon's tail," as it was called in the U.S., consumed a good deal of time and claimed at least two lives; see Harry K. Daghlian, Jr. and Louis Slotin.

> One of the key pieces of information, which Soviet intelligence obtained from Fuchs, was a cross-section for D-T fusion. [D-T stands for Deuterium-Tritium, so this is only relevant to fusion, ie hydrogen, bombs.]

> The single largest problem during the early Soviet project was the procurement of uranium ore, as the USSR had no known domestic sources at the beginning of the project. The Soviet F-1 reactor, which began operation in December 1946, was fueled using uranium confiscated from the remains of the German atomic bomb project. [The speed of Soviet bomb development seems to have been tightly constrained until discovery of the Kazakhstan uranium deposits in about 1947.]
> [image]

In regards [Soviet uranium supply prior to ~1970](https://www.spokesmanbooks.com/Spokesman/PDF/medvedev69.pdf):

> The American administration knew that uranium wasn’t mined in the Soviet Union. That was the main factor in their hope, which was dominant after 1943, of an atomic monopoly.

> On 8th December 1944, Stalin signed GKO Decision no.7102ss (‘ss’ meant ‘completely secret’). In accordance with this decision, all the programmes for mining and processing uranium were transferred from the commissariat for non- ferrous metals to the commissariat for internal affairs (NKVD) and put under L.P. Beria’s control.

> A transformation in the production of uranium was achieved. By the end of 1945, Combine No.6 had processed about 10,000 tonnes of uranium ore to produce seven tonnes of uranium concentrate. In 1946, 35,000 tonnes of uranium ore were processed. By the end of 1947, Combine No.6 consisted of seven uranium enrichment plants receiving ore from eighteen mines. 176,000 tonnes of uranium ore were processed, producing 66 tonnes of uranium concentrate. This guaranteed the production of almost 25 tonnes of uranium metal. In 1948, the
> production of uranium concentrate doubled. But this still did not satisfy the demands of the industrial reactor which had been built not far from the Urals town of Kyshtym. The greater part of the uranium which was loaded into this reactor in the spring and summer of 1948 consisted of uranium trophies found in Germany in June 1945, and from the established uranium mines in Czechoslovakia and Germany. Only in 1950, when the Leninabadsky combine was processing more than 600,000 tonnes of uranium ore every year, was the decisive significance of imports reduced. At this time, 18,000 people worked at Combine No.6, of whom 7,210 were prisoners.

Note that naturally occurring uranium is [only about 0.72% U-235](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235), the fuel from which uranium bombs are made. So not only must the uranium ore be smelted and refined to pure uranium; but it must then subsequently be [enriched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_uranium) to between 3.5% and 4.5% for (most) reactor use; or to roughly 85% for weapons use. To produce the 64 kg of enriched uranium used by the Little Boy bomb then required 64 kg * 80/0.72 = 7.1 tonnes of refined uranium metal; 17.8 tonnes of 40% uranium concentrate; and about 35,500  tonnes of uranium ore of the quality available from the Tadjikistan-Uzbekistan-Kirghiz mines. All hauled by mule, 70-100 kg at a time, over the area's rough mountainous terrain.

Comment: Then what stood in the way of the Germans developing a Hiroshima type bomb? Did they have a problem similar to the Iranians?

Comment: Yes - their [Peenemünde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peenem%C3%BCnde) plant was bombed by the allies, and their shipments of raw uranium from Sweden interdicted. The Germans did attempt, late in the war, to gift all their enriched uranium to Japan by submarine, but it as to little too late. The Germans also had resource-allocation issues, often due to Hitler constantly changing priorities.

Comment: @TomAu: I'd also note that the B-29 bomber program cost significantly more even than the Manhattan Project; and was, arguably at least, even more challenging technologically for the time.

Comment: According to wp, post-war a quite significant share of Soviet Uranium came from East German mines. Why did Germany need uranium from Sweden during the war? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wismut_(company)

Comment: How does this answer the question posed by the OP, "*...where did they come up with the money for the bomb?*"

Comment: Like Jan, I'm also confused by the reference to the interdiction of Swedish uranium. I didn't see much interdiction of e.g. Swedish iron ore. Were you instead referring to the interdiction of Norwegian heavy water transfers?en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_heavy_water_sabotage –

Comment: @Fred: Pieter (indirectly) answered the question by showing that the Hiroshima bomb was much less complicated and costly than I thought. The cheaper bomb not have required $2 billion. I had earlier thought that something like Moore's law as at work; the cost of certain technology falls by half every two years or so, declining by three quarters from 1945 to 1949.

Comment: @Jan: Mental slip. The heavy water needed by Germany for enrichment, not the uranium itself, came from Sweden. Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes.

Comment: @TomAu: Moore's Law applies to a very specific set of circumstances and one very specific technology: the number of transistors placeable on a single silicon wafer was doubling each generation because the previous chip generation allowed smaller and more precise chip doping. It was literally a positive feedback loop. We're unlikely to ever see the like again.

Comment: @TomAu Are you reading that as SU building first the Hiroshima type? They used one similar to Mk3/FatMan. Most German heavy water came from Norway (incl captured in France). SU found 100t UO in East Germany 45. SU isotope diff/enrichment process was better than US, but they copied US nonetheless (fear of reprisals internally). Etc SU bomb expected for 53/54. Question remains unanswered, not even indirectly, as this is tangential?

Comment: @Fred First paragraph (value (or cost) is a red herring).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: OK, it seems I confused nuclear "bombs" with missiles. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomAu they did. But also their nuclear program was first and foremost aimed at producing energy for the war industry. They therefore spent less effort (and funding) on Uranium enrichment and more on designing a natural Uranium reactor. This one might have produced Plutonium (depending on the design, I don't have data about that) but that wasn't their main purpose. At best Germany would have had a crude dirty bomb as a result of their project, using spent fuel as the material.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens  Sweden didn't at that time produce heavy water - the Rjukan plant in Norway did.  Producing heavy water requires access to cheap electric power (or power which doesn have competing buyers...)

Comment: "Wright's Law" governs most technologies. "Moore's Law" is just an" extreme" version of it; i.e., silicon productivity doubles every two years instead of every four or five.  https://www.forbes.com/sites/jimhandy/2013/03/25/moores-law-vs-wrights-law/?sh=31e7324577d2

Answer (score 1):

### Soviet system, frugality and spying

When we talk about real cost of Soviet atomic program, and military programs in general, we must first remember that money in Soviet economy was more of facade than real medium for exchange of goods. Soviet citizens had very low standard of living, especially during WW2 and immediately after it. Problem was not lack of money. No matter how much money you would have, you could not just buy essential items like food or even clothing, unless you had some kind of permit, coupons etc ... Alternatively, you could try black market at your own personal risk and at inflated prices. Consequently, it is hard to calculate how much hard currency (USD for example) Soviet Union spent on its atomic program, because Soviet rubles were not directly transferable to them. It is often said that during Stalin's years USSR spent more than 50% of its GDP on military-industrial complex. This is hard to prove or disprove, but it is usually taken as good ballpark estimate.

Now considering the Soviet atomic program, there are sources (in Russian) that give lot of technical and historical information like [this](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) or [this](https://aif.ru/society/history/bomba_podlinnaya_istoriya_sovetskogo_atomnogo_proekta), but without the cost. Still, some things could be deduced . History of Soviet atomic program before the first bomb could be roughly divided into two periods : preparation (September 1942 - August 1945) and finalization (August 1945 - August 1949) .

Even before that time Soviet scientist knew theory behind fission, especially concerning uranium isotopes . Several letters were sent to Stalin about possibility of atomic bomb. In September of 1941 Soviet spies in Britain did send information about UK uranium committee. Further information came in spring of 1942. Finally in September of 1942 Stalin decided it is necessary to work on this new kind of weapon. He signed decree of Commander in Chief No. 2372 "On the organization of work on uranium" and later in February of 1943 additional decree about atomic bomb program. Laboratories were created and scientific staff went to work, but in this phase this was mostly theoretical and experimental in small scale. Considering that in those war years Soviet scientist worked basically for free (they were content to have enough food for themselves and their families, plus warm place to sleep away from front line), it could be assumed that all of this didn't cost USSR too much . True, those same scientist could be employed to work on some other problems, but that is about it.

NKVD helped Soviet efforts a lot. In period of 1941-45 they obtained around 10 000 pages of documentation from USA and UK . According to Pavel Sudoplatov, this cut development time for Soviet atomic bomb in half. Throughout war years Soviet scientist worked on various problems like creating uranium-graphite reactor, reactor fueled by heavy water and on the bomb itself. Nevertheless, this work was mostly theoretical and laboratory - Soviets didn't have reactors themselves.

At the end of the war, Soviets managed to capture at that time significant quantities of uranium and uranium oxide from Germany (100 tonnes of uranium oxide at one place plus additional 12 tonnes of uranium at another). This was significant because before that they had uranium only in kilograms, and required tens of tonnes for a reactor. This further accelerated development of the bomb for at least a year. They also managed to recruit some German scientists (voluntarily or not) to help them with the project.

Overall, this first phase was not very expensive, and Soviets did have couple of lucky breaks. But in august of 1945 Americans used atomic weapons operationally against Japan. Having atomic weapons now moved from theoretical and experimental physics to grim political reality. Therefore, on 20th August of 1945 Special Committee with extraordinary powers was created (headed by Lavrentiy Beria) . This committee got "unlimited" financing and NKVD supplied workforce for all kinds of manpower needs. First experimental reactor was crated in December of 1946, it required around 45 tones of uranium. Second reactor, needed for plutonium production, required 150 tones. Do to low uranium production in USSR this could not be obtained until mid 1948, and then they had serious accident in late 1948 where thousands of people were irradiated, including head of the project Igor Kurchatov (it is believed that this caused his untimely death in 1960) . In any case, Soviets gathered enough plutonium for their first atomic device (RDS-1) in August 1949.

Since we are concerned with the cost, this second phase is more interesting to us. Phrases like "unlimited funds", 700 000 laborers for the project, creation of whole closed town ([Sarov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarov)) for the purpose of nuclear research etc ... certainly sound impressive . However, behind all of this is in fact "usual Soviet way of doing business" . Soviet economy heavily relied on forced labor, which was relatively ineffective but abundant. This goes especially for capital projects like canals, railroad and heavy industry. Calculating cost would be difficult because we cannot determine market price of work in socialist system. But what we do know for sure is that Soviet Union already had manpower (and other resources) available for capital projects. These projects would not produce consumer goods, in fact they were in most cases tied to Soviet military-industrial complex. Therefore, if not used for creating nuclear reactors and nuclear research facilities, they would be employed in building (for example) more tanks, not increasing agricultural production.

Final conclusion would be that nuclear weapons simply took part of already enormous (comparatively to the size of economy) military budget of USSR. They were simply another item that replaced some other obsolete weapon systems (like for example plans for building battleships and heavy cruisers) , but did not affect already overburdened Soviet economy . In fact, in the time of Khrushchev , due to gradual onset of MAD, they did help Soviet Union to somewhat reduce conventional forces and therefore increase living standard of its citizens. Therefore, overall effect would be economical benefit.

Comment: The soviets were a bit careful and wary about employing german scientists in their atomic bomb project - foreign scientists which doesn't want to disappear ? And so we will be required to allow to leave USSR and go back to East Germany (and which then will tell Berlin about their work in USSR... no thanks.)

Comment: With regards to costs and allocation of work force : it can explain the expansion of production (ie steel cement, and other products from heavy industry)  in the 30s with enforcement of the five-year plans and the change over to communism-in-one-country must survive.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund Yes, they were, but they still employed them in some cases, especially if their specialty was unique  . Of course, they kept them from direct involvement with weapons as much as they could.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund In an essence, Soviet nuclear program was just another grandiose heavy industry project, with accompanying use of unfree workforce. That is why the cost is difficult to judge - if not nuclear program those people would be employed in something similar related to military industrial complex.